# Ideal gas dimensional analysis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, dimensional-analysis

I was asked a question in 2 parts: Estimate the average distance between molecules for gas in your room at 300K and atmospheric temperature. Assuming the size of a gas molecule is roughly 0.2 nm, argue whether the ideal gas equation is an accurate model of the gas in the room.

I was able to calculate the first part as such:
$$PV=nRT $$
$$\frac{V}{N} = \frac{kT}{P}$$
$$\frac{V}{N} =  \frac{1.38*10^{-23} J/K * 300K}{10^5 N/m^{2}}$$
$$= 41 nm^{3}$$
Thus, the average distance between gas molecules is approximately
$$ \sqrt[3]{\frac{V}{N}}\qquad = \sqrt[3]{41 nm^{3}}\qquad = 3.5 nm$$.

My question is how we can use this answer/dimensional analysis, along with the assumption that the size of a gas molecule is roughly 0.2 nm, to argue whether the ideal gas equation is an accurate model of the gas in the room.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal gas equation uses various assumptions from the Kinetic theory of gases.

It's best to compare your answer to the size of the molecule and decide whether these assumptions are valid.